# Angularjs and angular 5 to work individually on two different app on same machine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular5

I have already existing app which is using Angularjs , now I want to make another app using Angular 5 which is completely independent of the existing app .

All I want to be sure of is that , can this scenario exists or will it create a problem for me for the existing app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not create any issue. You can develop Angularjs and Angualar (2, 4 or 5) app parallel in same machine.